# Remove subfolders from the url with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to mod_rewrite. I am trying to remove the subfolders coming in the URL and trying to display only directory name and the page section in the URL.

So, kindly help me with this.

**Note: This directory is in a folder!**
**Folder name -- training**

Here is my full directory structure:--

```
/
    /sites
        /all
            /themes
                /templates
                    node-1.tpl.php
                    node-2.tpl.php
                    node-3.tpl.php
    /assets
        /css
            ...
        /js
            ...
        /images
            ...
    /ajax
        ...
    /includes
        ...
    .htaccess
```

I want to rewrite the URL from:--

```
 https://localhost/training/php/sites/all/themes/templates/node-1.tpl.php
```

And change it to:--

```
https://localhost/training/php/home
```

And,
Here is what I tried in .htaccess:--

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home$ /sites/all/themes/templates/node-1.tpl.php
```

But I am getting this error:--

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.1
```

Comment: Is this URL `https://localhost/training/php/sites/all/themes/templates/node-1.tpl.php` reachable by a web browser?

Comment: Yes, It is reachable by web browser

Comment: Then you should use the rules in your   `/training/php/. htaccess`

Comment: The issue is that you have defined an _absolute_ path as rewriting target but forgot to set a `RewriteBase`.